# List index out of range - but it isnt

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, discord.py

Getting a list index out of range error for 'level = line[3].rstrip()'. Have double-checked everything, I print the list right before and over 4 values (of which I am trying to get the fourth) are shown. Code & traceback below, thanks!

Code:

```
async def lbcmd(ctx):
    el = []
    for file in os.scandir(lpath):
        if file.path.endswith(".txt"):
            with open(file, 'r') as f:
                line = f.readlines()
                level = line[3].rstrip()
                xp = line[0].rstrip()
                exp = {
                    "user": file.name.strip(".txt"),
                    "exp": xp,
                    "level": level
                    }
                el.append(exp)
    el.sort(reverse=True, key=operator.itemgetter('exp'))
    desc = ("""
""")
    for exp in el:
         desc = desc + f"""Level {exp['level']} at {exp['exp']} exp - <@{exp['user']}>
"""
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Level leaderboard", description=desc, color=0x2f3136)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Traceback:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jakec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\(A) Me\Coding\Python\jcjakec\Bots\conceptbot\conceptbot.py", line 144, in lbcmd
    level = line[3].rstrip()
IndexError: list index out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jakec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\jakec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jakec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range```
````

Comment: There is not enough information in this to replicate your problem.

Comment: I would suggest either print the complete line or length of line before the erroneous code and then update the same in your question. That way it will be easier for us to debug the issue.

Comment: Agree with above comments, include a print of the read data and the text file in questions (of course anonymized if it needs to be).

Comment: Hey all, sorry I didn't include enough information in my post, I'll try to structure future ones better. However, as I suspected, it was a stupid mistake. Resolved it all now. Sorry!

Comment: Add an answer if your question is resolved, might help others later